# How to calculate total transaction fees paid by users?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I want to calculate total transaction fees paid by users by using a `substrate-api-sidecar` on any substrate-based chain.

I tried reading two docs on calculating fees but none could help me out in deducing what to look for while querying a block. Click [here](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/weights/calculate-fees/) for document 1, [here](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/weights-and-fees/) for document 2.

Would that differ from chain to chain implementation?

I checked [Moonriver documents](https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/tools/sidecar/) on using substrate-api-sidecar and it seems possible to calculate fees. But I could not find out how to do so against a Polkadot parachain(relay chain)?

For setting the base premise, [Token Terminal](https://www.tokenterminal.com/terminal/projects/polkadot/key_metrics) states that in a blockchain, total revenue generated means total transaction fees paid by the users.

Comment: Hi, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66967801/1178971) seems to get the fee from an extrinsic using the polkadot-js API. This might help you.